# Is there a way to count the number of "Reopened" tickets in a JIRA?

Tags: jira, metrics, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I want to generate metrics for each version of my project what status I have that were reopened and closed.
For the "closed" it's ok, but for the "reopened" for old version now they are closed I can't find them in reopen status.
Is there a way to count the number of "Reopened" tickets in a JIRA project that they were closed now I can't find in normal filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just found a solution with advanced filter with an SQL code :

```
project = Name_of_my_project AND status WAS Reopened AFTER "-4w"
```

Comment: Yay solution! If you want to find issues which were reopened during that time, you could use something like "WAS NOT Reopened ON -4w AND WAS Reopened AFTER -4w".